# How do i get windows event log list by specific source C#

Tags: c#, windows, event-log

I want to get a list with event log by specific source .e.g. Outlook

I'm trying to use the following code, but I'm getting all application event logs.

Any idea?

Here is my code:

```
EventLog log = new EventLog("Application", computerName,specificSouarce);
```

Comment: Have you looked at the documentation?

Comment: Yes, That's what I've seen there, and I don't understand why it doesn't work. it sounds good

Answer (score 0):

How about using [System.Diagnostics.Eventing.Reader](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.eventing.reader):

```
var elQuery = new EventLogQuery("Application", PathType.LogName, "*[System/Provider/@Name=\"Outlook\"]");
using (var reader = new EventLogReader(elQuery))
{
    var eventRecord = reader.ReadEvent();
    try
    {
        for (; eventRecord != null; eventRecord = reader.ReadEvent())
        {
            // Do what you want on the event
            Console.WriteLine($"{eventRecord.TimeCreated}: {eventRecord.FormatDescription()}");
        }
    }
    finally
    {
        if (eventRecord != null)
            eventRecord.Dispose();
    }
}
```

FYI: I develop [a GUI app](https://github.com/kmaki565/EventLook) that can filter event logs by various conditions.